# HTML form to go to new page and start download

Tags: php, html, header

I have an HTML form like so:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="script.php" align="center">
    <input type="submit" value="Run Program"/>
</form>
```

Then I have the PHP page, script.php. I would it to be displayed and also begin a download automatically. However, when I add the header for starting the download:

```
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $_FILES['upload']['name'] . '.tbx');
header('Content-Type: application/force-download');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($tbx));
```

the download is started but the page itself is not loaded (probably because the headers say that we are just going to transfer a file). How do I make the page properly display *and* automatically start a download?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to load the HTML page first, then at the end of the page perform a JavaScript location request to the download file.

```
<html>
... your HTML ....
<script type="text/javascript">
document.location = '... location of file to download ...';
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Great, thanks! Since it was in a PHP script `echo` command, though, I had to use `window.onload = function () { window.location = $url; }` so that the whole page would be loaded before redirecting and so I could have a separate PHP page with the download logic.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that server-side.  You have to do that client-side.

You can only send one resource at a time over HTTP!  Just send a page that includes a JavaScript redirect to your download script.